# Delete this token (else)

Tags: java

ok so i was playing round with some code and adding new line as i'm learning java. i got this error  "syntax error token "else" delete this token".

As im new to this could some one explain this error and what i should do, so i do not make the same mistake again.

class Years {

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    int age = 30;

    if (age <30){

        System.out.println("you are young");

    }else{

        System.out.println("you are old ");

        if (age > 1240);
    }else{

        System.out.println("dam son your still a bady");

        if (age < 25);
        {


            System.out.println("You are Really old son!!");

        }else{

            System.out.println("you better Hide your age son!!"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If age is >= 30, which of your two else statements should be executed?

Comment: You have 4 possible age bands, but five outputs... what are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an *unconditional* `else` block - you can't follow that with another `else`. So this is fine:

```
if (condition) {
    ...
} else if (otherCondition) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

But this isn't - because it doesn't make sense:

```
if (condition) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

An `else` block without a condition is meant to run unconditionally if the condition above it was not satisfied - in your case, the middle block is *always* run, so it's meaningless to have another.

Also note that you have:

```
if (age > 1240);
```

... which I suspect you didn't really intend. Likewise:

```
if (age < 25);
```

Both of these are `if` statements with empty bodies.

It's really unclear what you *expect* to achieve in each case - but I'd strongly advise you to have something like:

```
// List all the age boundaries in increasing order...
if (age < 25) {
   ...
} else if (age < 30) {
   ...
} else if (age < 1240) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Now *exactly* one of those bodies will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a condition which doesn't make sense:

```
if (something) {

} else {

} else {

}
```

How do you expect the system to know which "else" block to use?  `else` logically means "otherwise, do this" and effectively captures all remaining conditions.  You can't do that more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got an `if` statement that's in the wrong place. Try this instead:

```
if (age <30){

    System.out.println("you are young");

}else if (age > 1240){

    System.out.println("you are old ");

}else{

    System.out.println("dam son your still a bady");

    if (age < 25);
    {

        System.out.println("You are Really old son!!");

    }else{

        System.out.println("you better Hide your age son!!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First understand how if statements work in any programming language. For example [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) is a good resource for you to understand if statements in java. I'm not 100% sure about what are you trying achieve by this code. But I can give you one hint. When branching, use not only `else` but also `else if()`.